# Asus TUF A15's camera and microphone not working

Tags: asus, microphone, camera

My Asus Tuf A15 laptop's camera and microphone stopped working suddenly. Not sure what caused the issue. When I open cheese, it is showing **No device found**. The microphone is also not working.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you see these devices if you list up your hardware? sudo lshw

Comment: I'm not able to see anything with the name camera or related to camera. All I can see are core, display, multimedia (but not camera in it), some pci bridges, storage, USB, data, etc.